# Keras 'one_hot' for text processing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, word-embedding, text-processing

Suppose I have sequence of word/ sentence: "I like food"

If I enconde with keras one_hot:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
one_hot('I like food',50)
```

it gives me the following values:[10, 39, 17]

However, suppose I have a sequence of entry like this: ['Add more', 'Add less', 'Do little more']
Here each of the entries is like a word in a sentence. Therefore, I want to encode 'Add more', 'Add less', and 'Do little more' as a single word.   All of the entries consist of full sequence or sentence.

How can I encode this like one_hot in keras. Using one_hot it shows error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to preprocess your text and combine words with an underscore. So your input to Keras would look like this:

```
"add_more add_less do_little_more"
```

Typically this is done for phrases that are always used together in normal language, like "New York"; these are sometimes called **multi-word expressions** (MWEs) in academic papers. If you combine a lot of words like this you might end up with data that's too sparse to use, but you can try it.